# How to align graph and the access in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

So I really **dislike** formatting in Excel. When you have a scattered plot and lines that connect the scatter how do you get the labels to align with the month labels?

This one is unaligned.
[image]

This is aligned (note this image has been altered in an image editor)
[image]

I have tried to edit the date for the points, such as making it all the first of the month or the end of the month, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get better alignment between the tics and the data points when using the **Line graphs**. Scatter plots are designed to be at the measure locations. So change to line graphs.